# How can I adjust the responsive design of images and text with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a group of divs that are editable and draggable, these divs allow you to build the design of a web page, that is, these div are positioned and created with these the design of a page that is then shown to the user. The problem is in getting responsiveness for the design created with these divs. The view of this page on Tablet and mobile is totally out of responsivity. Here I show code that I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".caja1").draggable();
  $(".caja1").resizable();

});
```

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

div.caja1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

div.caja1 {
  background: rgb(83, 53, 117)
}

@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) 
           {
 div.caja1
  {                                     max-width: 255px !important;
width: 255px !important;
left: 0px !important;                      
margin-right: 0px !important;
     }
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

NOTE: The div that is created can be moved and drop anywhere in its container, thanks to the draggable() function of Jquery-UI, its width and height can be modified thanks to the resizable() function of Jquery UI and also its content is editable. I can create several divs and place them where I want and then I save that html in database and I show it on my main web page (which is created with bootstrap). The problem is that when I see that content created on mobile or tablet everything looks bad and nothing responsive. Also, each div has its top and left values ​​that vary since the location of the divs can be changed with draggable () and also have their values ​​of width and height that are not fixed since with jquery resizable they can be adjusted.

Then How to achieve responsiveness in these types of situations? The container where the divs are has a relative position and each div has an equally relative position. Here is a sample image where you can see the desktop version of the content that I create and the mobile version as well:

DESKTOP VERSION
[image]

OBILE VERSION
[image]

In the code that I have placed above I have a small css code for half queries.

Explanation of the images: In the first image (desktop version) Each text and each image is inside a div, so, there are several divs there. Exactly 7 divs, the div of the title, the 3 divs of the 3 images and 3 divs for the 3 texts that are below each image.

SO, YOU HAVE SEEN THE PROBLEM IN THE MOBILE VERSION IMAGE?

How can I solve this issues?

Comment: try to use bootstrap 4 grid system That will definitely help you [https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp]

Answer (score 2):

**try this code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <style>
  div.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*padding-left: 10px;*/
}
div.container .row{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

div.caja1 {
  width: calc( 32% - 15px);
  margin: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

div.caja1 {
  background: rgb(83, 53, 117)
}

@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) 
           {
            div.container .row{
              justify-content: center;
            }
 div.caja1
  {                                     max-width: 255px !important;
width: 255px !important;
left: 0px !important;                      
margin-right: 0px !important;
     }
 }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script type="">
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".caja1").draggable();
  $(".caja1").resizable();

});
  </script>  

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
      <div class="editable-div">
        <p style="color: black;font-size: 34; font-weight: bold; font-style: initial; color: black; width: auto;" contenteditable="true">
          this is text

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is almost the solution, but the problem is that when I move one of the divs and put it in another position, and then review the design in mobile, that div is over another div and that is what I really want to solve.